# What is the generic term for database tables, views, functions, and stored procedures?

Tags: database, terminology

The question title pretty much says it all.

What is the generic term for database tables, views, functions, stored procedures, et al?

Surely there is some term that can be used to describe these generically. Perhaps there is none, but I would have thought there would been a generally accepted industry term like "artifact" or "object".

---

EDIT: I'm not looking for the collective environmental term (i.e. a schema) or a term for the definitions of those objects (i.e. DDL scripts). I'm looking for a term that describes generically a **database component**, whether it be a table, view, function, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*imported from comments per OP's request*)

I'm afraid "database objects/entities" is the best you can get.

Comment: This seems most reasonable and generic to me. I prefer Database Objects over Database Entities, as "entities" is a very loaded term these days, especially in regards to data.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

In a relational database, the schema defines the tables, fields, relationships, views, indexes, packages, procedures, functions, queues, triggers, types, sequences, materialized views, synonyms, database links, directories, XML schemas, and other elements.

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm

Comment: This is a term for the group collectively. Think "A schema is a collection of ...". What is the ...?

Comment: Looking at that link it uses the term "Schema Objects". A little research shows that that term has different meanings to different RDMS providers - some use it to refer to the objects inside a schema, others use it to refer to the schema itself.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS - This is the generic term for database , tables , triggers , procedures ... etc

Answer (score -2):

DDL - which is a TLA for either data definition language or data description language.

Comment: The language, not the objects.

Comment: DDL refers to the language definition. You might have DDL scripts, but those scripts create the objects. It's the generic term for the objects that I'm after.

Comment: It's definitely used in common parlance to refer to the objects generically.

Comment: "It's definitely used in common parlance" - Citation needed. I have _never_ heard this used in this meaning. How would this even sound? "Hey, tell me about your new project. Is the database big?" "Hell yeah, over 3000 DDLs".

Comment: I've heard the term DDL, it's generally used to refer to a text file that contains the script to create a database object. Like a `CREATE TABLE` script, you would call that text file a DDL.